# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, config

I am working on an existing project and It has 3 project

```
a  myProject.Web
b  myProject.ServiceLayer
c  myProject.ServieLayer.Test
```

when I run the test project it requires ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] and App setting is Present in a Web project. I don't want to add System.web in my Tests Project. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a reference to System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager and copy the config file to your test project.